# How to install the DAML SDK in a Ubuntu VM, which doesn't have the internet connection?

Tags: daml

Unable to install the "da-cli-114-7582c1a0bd-linux.run" file in my Ubuntu VM.  The setup is failing while checking the latest version check.

I have downloaded the latest DAML SDK setup file "da-cli-114-7582c1a0bd-linux.run" and copied the same into my Ubuntu VM through local network connection.  When I try to install the .run file, the setup trying to connect to the internet for latest version check.  But I am not allowed to use internet in the application servers/VMs.  Because of this restriction the setup is getting failed and I am unable to complete the DAML SDK installation.

Is it possible to get the DAML SDK setup as a .tar file?  If we have tar file, then it will be easy to complete the setup manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing the SDK using the `.run` files in an environment without an internet connection is not easy. It might be possible to install it in an environment with internet and then tar up the folder `~/.da`, extract it back into place in the VM and put `~/.da/bin`.

However, there is a new SDK assistant in the works (called `daml`, not `da`), which can be installed using `curl -sSL get.daml.com | sh`. If you look at the content of the installation script, you can see that all it really does is downloading a tar-ball from [GitHub releases](https://github.com/digital-asset/daml/releases/), un-tars it and calls an `install.sh` script within. That's probably the easier way to get the SDK into an offline environment at this point.

However, the documentation for the new `daml` assistant is not on docs.daml.com yet. It will be shortly, but in the meantime you can read it [on GitHub](https://github.com/digital-asset/daml/blob/daml-assistant-doc/docs/source/tools/assistant.rst).

Comment: The new DAML assistant is now available on docs.daml.com.  

Here is the URL -> https://docs.daml.com/support/new-assistant.html  

Thank you  
Augustine